# All ubuntu-based distros freeze on 2nd startup

Tags: suspend, kde-neon

For the last little while now, I've been having problems with my computer when it starts up again after sleeping. Every time that happens, the time it takes to freeze the computer varies. When that happens, even though I don't have an SD card inserted in my laptop's front slot, it seems as though that SD card processor indicator was constantly lit. The only way to manage it was to force-shutdown my computer. To be more specific, I'm running a Toshiba Satellite A305 with KDE Neon 22.04, an Ubuntu-based distro. I've had this problem with almost every Ubuntu-based distro, obviously including KDE Neon. Any permanent fixes for this?

Sincerely, SaturaniumYT

Comment: I did notice that on another Ubuntu-based distro, Kubuntu, had a larger SWAP partition and I think it significantly lowered the amount of times the computer froze. Maybe that could be a clue to the solution?

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347924/20-04-freezes-after-waking-up-from-suspend maybe?

Comment: It says there that the PrtSc REISUB worked there whereas in my case it didnt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Thinkpad T14: System freeze after second suspend.

My solution was to change the BIOS setup:

- BIOS -> Power modes -> change from "Windows and Linux" to "Linux S3"

Comment: I don’t know if that is possible to do on my laptop, since a good handful of settings are greyed out, due to the fact that it was built sometime between 2008 and 2009. I will see if I can give this a shot but again, I am uncertain if I will actually be able to.

Comment: I have confirmed that this does not work for my laptop. My laptop does not have any power config options in its BIOS setup.

P.s. apologies for the late response.